# Why is javascript callback function not executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can someone explain why callback function after loadData(symbol) is not being called?  I have this function:

```
    function plotChart(symbol) {
        alert("symbol: " + symbol);
        var data = loadData(symbol, function(){
            console.log("data: ",data);
        });
    }
```

I'm expecting `log.console` to execute after `loadData` completes, but nothing gets output.

In case it matters, here is the loadData function.

```
    function loadData(symbol) {
    count = 0;
    quotes = [];
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes-between?symbol=IBM&startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-09-30", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(item){
            var quote = {};
            quote.date   = item.id.date.substring(0,10);
            quote.open   = item.open;
            quote.high   = item.high;
            quote.low    = item.low;
            quote.close  = item.close;
            quote.volume = item.volume;
            quotes.push(quote); //put quote in array
        });
        console.log("quotes: ",quotes);  
        return quotes;
    });
}
```

Here the console.log successfully prints out the quotes correctly.

**EDIT**:
Per @Aluan, I changed the code to look like this:

```
    function plotChart(symbol) {
        loadData(symbol).then(function(data) {
            console.log("data: ", data);
        });
    }

    function loadData(symbol) {
        quotes = [];
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes-between?symbol=" +symbol +"&startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-09-30") 
            .then(function (data) {
            const quotes = data.map(function(item) {
                return {
                    date: item.id.date.substring(0,10),
                    open: item.open,
                    high: item.high,
                    low : item.low,
                    close: item.close,
                    volume: item.volume
                };
            });
            console.log("quotes: ",quotes);  
            return quotes;
        });
    }
```

But now I'm getting error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at plotChart (moneymachine.html:120)
at HTMLTableRowElement.

Line 120 is                 `loadData(symbol).then(function(data) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `loadData` is essential to understanding the reason.

Given

```
function loadData(symbol) {
    count = 0;
    quotes = [];
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes-between?symbol=IBM&startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-09-30", function (data) {
        data.forEach(function (item) {
            var quote = {};
            quote.date   = item.id.date.substring(0, 10);
            quote.open   = item.open;
            quote.high   = item.high;
            quote.low    = item.low;
            quote.close  = item.close;
            quote.volume = item.volume;
            quotes.push(quote); //put quote in array
        });
        console.log("quotes: ", quotes);  
        return quotes;
    });
}
```

We can see that it defines one parameter, `symbol`. You may pass additional arguments when calling it, but it clearly does not use them.

When you write

```
var data = loadData(symbol, function () {
    console.log("data: ", data);
});
```

The second argument is simply ignored.

Here's an example of `loadData` that would accept and make use of a second argument that's a callback.

```
function loadData(symbol, callback) {
    count = 0;
    quotes = [];
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes-between?symbol=IBM&startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-09-30", function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(item){
            var quote = {};
            quote.date   = item.id.date.substring(0, 10);
            quote.open   = item.open;
            quote.high   = item.high;
            quote.low    = item.low;
            quote.close  = item.close;
            quote.volume = item.volume;
            quotes.push(quote); //put quote in array
        });
        callback(data) // here
        console.log("quotes: ", quotes);  
    });
}
```

However, this definition of `loadData` is suboptimal at best. It should make use of the *thenable* return by jQuery's `$.getJson`, to make the code clearer.

```
function loadData(symbol) {
    return $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/springboot-crud-rest/api/v1/quotes-between?symbol=IBM&startDate=2020-01-01&endDate=2020-09-30")
        .then(function (data) {
            const quotes = data.map(function (item) {
                return {
                    date: item.id.date.substring(0, 10),
                    ...item
                };
            });
            console.log("quotes: ", quotes);
            return quotes;
        });
}
```

Consumed as

```
loadData('something').then(function (data) {
    console.log("data: ", data);
});
```

Comment: I know that the symbol argument is not being used for now.  But are you saying that because it is not used, the callback function is being ignored?  I do not find that deeply indented code makes it clearer.  Just the opposite for me.   I also don't understand what callback(data) does or why it is needed.But I will give it a try. Thank you Aluan!

Comment: I changed my code to look like yours as updated in the EDIT of the original post, but now getting a new problem.

Comment: I couldn't get your second example to work, but I did get the first one working.  I understand better now.  I was passing a function as an argument but failing to call that function from loadData when it was done.  I had thought that would happen automatically.  Only where you say callback(data), I say callback(quotes).  That worked.

Comment: @user3217883 I reviewed your edit the question. When you copy the second version you've missed something. You forgot return. That's why it failed

Comment: Ah, ok I see that now.  Anyway I'm keeping the first version.  The second one is too hard for me to understand.